# App keeps dying after http request results are put into layout

Tags: android, multithreading, http, request

I honestly could not think of a good title. Sorry. Anyway, so I have an app that I am making where I pull information from my custom web api. I pull data from the api and fill in the layout with this information. Problem is it takes a while so the app stalls for a few seconds before the information is pulled since it is in the onCreate method of the activity. To resolve this I implemented a loading dialog. This is where the problems began. I put the http requests into a seperate thread and it downloads fine. No problem. However it keeps force closing every time I try to modify the layout afterward. So basically my question is how do I modify the layout after the background thread is finished? Everything I try keeps force closing the app.

Comment: you've got NPE at com.informaldebates.Main.generateUserProfile(Main.java:203) (if I read your log correctly). Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use an asynctask. You're trying to update the UI from a different thread. You can't do that. There's about 11 billion other questions on this exact same subject

Comment: I've tried that. That's where I am now. It still force closes saying I am unable to change a view from a different thread. Does this mean asynctask should allow me to modify the UI from within the asynctask? If so then maybe I'm doing the asynctask wrong?

Comment: Put the UI update stuff in onPostExecute and put the background stuff in doInBackground.  onPostExecute runs on the UI thread and doInBackground obviously runs on a background thread.

Comment: That didn't work. It still throws an error. Here is the logcat output if it helps:


D/AndroidRuntime(15743): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(15743): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e8)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15743): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at com.informaldebates.Main.generateUserProfile(Main.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at com.informaldebates.Main$LoadingThread.onPostExecute(Main.java:115)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at com.informaldebates.Main$LoadingThread.onPostExecute(Main.java:1)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(15743):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Edit your original post. Do you really think that log is readable?

Comment: And you're getting a null pointer exception, has nothing to do with the UI thread and views.